Fit data to a lookup table
I have been looking for methods to fit 1-D data to a lookup table. In other words, there's no known function that is used as a model.
For example in the plots below, the measured data (blue) is fit to a a model (orange) but the model is not a function per se, just a lookup table.
Any insights will be greatly appreciated.


This question might be better asked in a place like [scicomp.SE], but a question first: Did you try smoothing rather than fitting?

What does "fit to a lookup table" mean?  I'm confused.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  What is the desired output?

the input to the algorithm is the blue line (all noisy and everything). The blue line is a list of points (x,y), the orange line would be the desired lookup table that fits the blue line.

Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.  Don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question so someone who comes across the question for the first time can understand what you are asking.  I don't understand why you call the orange line a "lookup table"; that is not the usual meaning of the term.  What properties do you want the orange line to have?  Why not output the exact same as the input?  What requirement does that violate?  Do you want it to be "smooth", for some definition of smooth, and if so, by what definition?

For those who have the same question. The answer is non-parametric regression
https://www.kaggle.com/code/residentmario/non-parametric-regression
